# In R, how do I extract minutes and seconds from characters

Tags: r, time

I'm trying to split a column from R into minutes and seconds.  Problem is, the column is simply numeric:  for example it will have "752","843","823", "956", (up to about 2000 being the highest) etc... which stands for 7 mins and 52 seconds, 8 minutes and 43 seconds, 8 minutes and 23 seconds, etc...  I'd like to split it into two columns.  One column for the number of minutes, one for the number of seconds.  I'll then use those columns to create a third, "totalSeconds" which would have "472" for the 7 minutes and 52 seconds.

I've been searching all over, checking out regular expressions, etc..  I just can't seem to figure it out.  Another similar question on here pointed me towards the function 'substr'  but I am stuck on that because each variable does not always have the same number of characters in it, i.e. 752 vs 1145.  Any help?  Or at least maybe somebody could point me in the right direction?

Comment: What does 2000 stand for?

Comment: @RStudent I think that would be 20 minutes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could consider `separate` from "tidyr". Here, I use it in conjunction with `mutate` from "dplyr" to get the output you are looking for.

Note that `separate` lets you specify either from the left of the string or from the right of the string depending on whether the `sep` value is positive or negative. This would allow us to deal with cases like "1000" appropriately.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df %>% 
  separate(secs, into = c("min", "sec"), sep = -3) %>% 
  mutate(tot = as.numeric(min)*60 + as.numeric(sec))
#   min sec tot
# 1   7  52 472
# 2   8  43 523
# 3   8  23 503
# 4   9  56 596
# 5  10  00 600
```

#### Sample data:

```
df <- data.frame(secs = c("752","843","823", "956", "1000"))
```

Answer (score 2):

If the last two elements of your characters represent seconds and the remaining first one/two element/s represent minutes, then try the following:

```
res <- data.frame(v = v, minutes = substr(v, 1, nchar(v)-2), seconds = substr(v, nchar(v)-1, nchar(v)))
> res
    v minutes seconds
1 752       7      52
2 843       8      43
3 823       8      23
4 956       9      56
```

In order to calculate the total amount of seconds:

```
res <- as.data.frame(apply(res, 2, function(x) as.double(as.character(x))))
res$tot.sec <- res$minutes*60 + res$seconds
> res
    v minutes seconds tot.sec
1 752       7      52     472
2 843       8      43     523
3 823       8      23     503
4 956       9      56     596
```

Answer (score 0):

In this example:

```
 df=data.frame(D=round(1000*runif(100)))
```

D is the column that has your strings. If you do:

```
df$MIN=ifelse(nchar(df$D)>=3,substr(df$D, 0,1),0) #if there are only seconds
```

this would return the minutes

and

```
df$SEC=substr(df$D, nchar(df$D)-1,nchar(df$D))
```

would return the seconds.

Is this what you want?

Comment: This was almost it, it would split something like 815 correctly, but anything like 1000 would get messed up, becoming 1 and 00.